# Push JavaScript in while loop with column name from JS table

Tags: javascript

i have some code while loop and push in JS:

```
var externalDataRetrievedFromServerAreas = "";
while.....
{
externalDataRetrievedFromServerAreas.push({COLUMNNAME: 
document.getElementById('table1').rows[i].cells[j].innerHTML});
}
```

and here i want to have column name instead of 'COLUMNNAME', for example like this:

```
document.getElementById('table1').rows[0].cells[j].innerHTML
```

but i have an error, doing this way.

Can someone please help?

Comment: @VarunS The OP doesn't seem to have a `COLOUMNNAME` variable...

Comment: i can create variable one step before or just do like this:  { [document.getElementById('table1').rows[1].cells[j].innerHTML]: document.getElementById('table1').rows[i].cells[j].innerHTML}); }

Comment: You can't use `push` on strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var externalDataRetrievedFromServerAreas = [];
while.....
{
const COLUMNNAME = document.getElementById('table1').rows[0].cells[j].innerHTML
externalDataRetrievedFromServerAreas.push({ [COLUMNNAME]: 
document.getElementById('table1').rows[i].cells[j].innerHTML});
}
```